# Fetch API work in postman but do not work in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch-api

I want to fetch my API in react native but react  does not show my result, this API  showing in postman but do not show in react native, after I change my API this works for me but does not show in this API.
My code is :

```js
fetch('http://roomarket.ir/LlIi1/CT.php')
  .then((response13) => response13.json())
    .then((response3) => {
      this.setState({Alert.alert(response3.ENtime)})
```

How do I fetch it in react native? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
fetch('http://roomarket.ir/LlIi1/CT.php')
  .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseData) => {
      this.setState({response:responseData. ENtime},() => Alert.alert(this.state.response))
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CORS Headers issue. Example fiddle which shows fetch is failing with different domain name : https://jsfiddle.net/98to6za0/

```js
fetch('http://roomarket.ir/LlIi1/CT.php')
  .then((response13) => response13.json())
    .then((response3) => {
      console.log(response3);
    });
```

With postman it will work since there are no cors controls enforced on the url.

**API need to be enabled for cors :** [CORS with php headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers)

**You can read more about CORS here :** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS